# can not make a select with the desired values in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Creating the table

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.factura
(
     customer_code varchar(20),
     invoice_number char(4),
     line_number char(2), 
     data date
);
    
DROP TABLE dbo.factura;

SELECT * FROM dbo.factura;
```

Populating the table:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.factura VALUES ('ABC', '0012', '01', '2020-10-01');
INSERT INTO dbo.factura VALUES ('ABC', '0012', '02', '2020-11-01');
INSERT INTO dbo.factura VALUES ('ABC', '0012', '03', '2020-11-01');
INSERT INTO dbo.factura VALUES ('ABC', '0013', '08', '2021-01-21');
INSERT INTO dbo.factura VALUES ('ABC', '0013', '09', '2020-09-01');
INSERT INTO dbo.factura VALUES ('SLIK', '0001', '01', '2021-01-01');
INSERT INTO dbo.factura VALUES ('SLIK', '0001', '02', '2020-02-01');
```

Write a SQL statement to return the recordset:

```
CUSTOMER_CODE, INVOICE_NR, LINE_NR
```

where `NR_LINE` is the line number with the most recent value in the `DATA` column for each invoice of each customer in the table.

I tried to do with a self join, but it doesn't work.

Do you have any ideas how to write this query?

Comment: select a.cod_client, a.nr_factura, a.nr_linie
 from dbo.factura  a, dbo.factura b
 where a.nr_factura = b.nr_factura and a.cod_client = b.cod_client 
 order by  a.data desc

Comment: select a.customer_code, a.invoice_number, a.line_number from factura a, factura b, where a.invoice_number = b.invoice_number and a.customer_code = b.customer_code order by a.data desc ........In English

Comment: which database you are using?

Comment: sql server - transact sql

Answer (score 0):

If you want the rows by sorted by line_number in descending order then the query will be:

```
with cte as (
    select CUSTOMER_CODE, INVOICE_number, LINE_number , row_number()over(partition by customer_code,invoice_number order by LINE_number desc) rn
from factura
)
select CUSTOMER_CODE, INVOICE_number, LINE_number from cte where rn=1
```

**Output:**

[image]

If you want the result in descending order of data field then the query will be:

```
with cte as (
    select CUSTOMER_CODE, INVOICE_number, LINE_number , row_number()over(partition by customer_code,invoice_number order by data desc) rn
from factura
)
select CUSTOMER_CODE, INVOICE_number, LINE_number from cte where rn=1
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: the desired output is ABC 0012 02
ABC 0013 08
SLIK 0001 02

Comment: ABC 0012 02
ABC 0013 08
SLIK 0001 02

Comment: without the data field and the third row should be SLIK 0001 02

Comment: Only the third row is not fine, but I don't understand why

Comment: we can ommit the data field in the select, I need only the third 3 fields, but what can we do with the third row?

Comment: for SLIK 0001 line_number 01 has date 2021-01-01 which is greater than 2020-02-01 of line number 02.

Comment: Now if you want the result order by line_number instead of data then line_number for three rows will be 03, 09 and 02. Though third row will be as you desire but first and second rows will be changed. Is it ok?

Comment: this is the final result https://ibb.co/BcMXYPf , but in your case only first 2 rows are ok, the third one not, why?

Comment: Because for SLIK 0001 most recent date is 2021-01-01 which has the line_number 01. Please check the two rows for SLIK 0001.

Comment: @VladalexandruVlad Please let me know your feed-back.

Comment: my mistake, thank you so much, everything is perfect , I should check your implementation with documentation because I have never used it like that..thanks again

Comment: My pleasure. Best wishes.

Comment: I want to check to add the dest value and then check if it's null  private void addEdge(int sou, int?dest)
 {
  adj[sou].Add(dest);
  if(dest.HasValue) some code...
 }

Comment: but I can't add dest to the List if I put ?dest as parameter

Comment: If you are assigning dest to a intiger variable then it will cause error. int? cannot be cast to int implicitly.  you can uae Convert.ToInt32(dest).